# Migrating using Opshub Utility

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

I'm currently trying to migrate TFS 2010 to visualstudio.com.
However, I have the following message on my screen at this very moment:

"Configuration created successfully. Do you want to start migration of x to y.visualstudio.com?"

Does this migration delete the data on the current TFS or does it leave it untouched? Because I'm trying to migrate it as a test and do not want the current TFS to be modified by this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OVSMU Tool does **not** in any circumstance **modify/write** something in your source instance.
So, don't worry and carry on with your migration.